# What enable test run do on Release Updates

Tags: administration, release-update

I got this from [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release_updates.htm&type=5)

> When you enable a test run, the update becomes immediately enabled in
> your org. The test run allows you to evaluate the impact of the update
> before the update is enforced.

[image]

So, what I have understood from here is, Enable Test Run button allows me to evaluate the impact.
But in the lower part, you can see a **Done** button. What is the button for?

Comment: I believe that will be to indicate the percentage of testing done. Like if only one update is there then pressing done will move the progress bar to 100%. An then the Enable test run button should change to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Done** button is a final confirmation and an acknowledgment that you have completed all the recommended steps required to test the critical update. Once the done button is clicked you will see the below screen and after providing the confirmation, you will see the following example message

> You've completed all recommended steps. Enforcement scheduled: Summer
> '21.

[image]

[image]

**Enable Test Run** enables the critical update. Clicking the button shows the following message

> This update is now enabled for testing

**Note**: You can enable and disable the update during the test period, which ends on the “Complete steps by" date. For a sandbox org, the test period can end early with a release upgrade